# Prove the formula is a contadiction

Tags: logic, proof-verification

> For every $A$ in Propositional calculus and for every $\rho$ we
>   define:
>
> $$A^\rho = \begin{cases}
>     A & \text{if $[|A|]_\rho = true$} \\
>      \lnot A & \text{if $[|A|]_\rho = false$}   \end{cases} $$
>
> Prove that for $A$ which has the variables $B_1,\ldots,B_n$, the
>   following formula is a logical contradiction:
>
> $$B_1^\rho\land \cdots \land B_n\land \lnot (A^\rho)$$

Now, I really don't understand the difficulty here. I mean, in any case $(\lnot A^\rho)$ will become $\mathrm{false}$.

What am I missing? It shouldn't be that easy.

Comment: What does the $\rho$ mean, also the $|A|$ and given those, is the use of the square brackets just like a gouping device (like usual parentheses in e.g. $(x+1)^2$)?

Comment: It's just a notation. $\rho$ is a function from variables to $\{t,f\}$.

Comment: Correct: $(A^{\rho})$ is always *true* and thus...

Answer (score 1):

If $A^\rho$ is always true by definition, then $\neg(A^\rho )$ is always false. That would render the whole conjunction $B_1\wedge\dots\wedge B_n\wedge \neg(A^\rho )$ always false. There is the contradiction.